# Banno API, can't access User_id to be able to run any other APIs

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit, jackhenry-jxchange

I am trying to inquire on customer transfer limits to be able to change them dynamically based on other criteria. This is where I run into a snag, I have the Online Banking IDs I would like to change but getting the User_ID to be able to call any Banno API has proven more difficult than I had hoped. Talking with support they said there aren't any APIs that translate the Online Banking ID to Banno User_ID, and no reports give us this info it has to be pulled from the URL on individual customers which can't possibly be the answer. How are people accessing the Banno User_ID?

I am authenticating properly and getting a 200 code but says invalid request since I'm using the wrong ID.

Request attempting to retrieve the User_ID:

```
/consumer/api/v0/users/<%OnlineBankingId%>
```

Response:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2024 18:11:55 GMT
ETag: [Not sure if this is private]

Invalid request
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am following the question correctly, you are using the [GET /users/{userId}](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/user/details/#/User%20Functions/get_users__userId_) endpoint - this requires the `userId`, I'm not sure what you're referring to when you mention the "Online Banking IDs" but it sounds like you are using the username. This endpoint does not accept that as the input.

An alternative I would recommend using the [GET /a/consumer-user-search/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/consumers/consumer-user-search/#/User%20Search/get_a_consumer_user_search_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users) using the Admin API.

This endpoint accepts a `query` when so that you can search for the user, this will return an array of users with a hash where you can retrieve the `userId`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for! Question, is the InstitutionID a 4 digit number found in the URL when logged into Banno.com/a?

I am getting a 404 error with that path using our 4 digit institutionID I found.

The body of my request:
{
query:"{Redacted NetTellerID}"
}

Comment: Your request body is correct, but you will also need to provide the access token. That is not the institution ID. I would suggest taking a look at the Authentication quickstart (https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/quickstarts/authentication/) to see how to get your access token as well as institution id.

Also see this guide for an example of the search: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/guides/usersupporttools/#get-aconsumer-user-searchapiv0institutionsinstitutionidusers